# VtigerCRM 7.0, scheduler don't work

Tags: cron, vtiger, vtigercrm

Hello to everyone and thank you in advance,
I am in a company that has started using the vtigerCRM 7.0 open source on Linux and as we worked out the creation of the workflows to send emails and so on we set the scheduler to run crons for the workflows every 15 minutes, but it never runs. Is there anything we can do to make the scheduler work?
Kind Regards,
Dimitris

Answer (score 1):

First step is to check cron setup.

Using `crontab -e` you will find the details of cron job.

You should define the cron as below:

```
* * * * * {Full path of vtiger directory/cron/vtigercron.sh  >/dev/null 2>&1
```

Once you define the workflow you can test the workflow by calling cron file directly as below:

```
http://{crm url}/vtigercron.php
```

Make sure than you have set the 775 permission to cron folders and their files.

Hope this will help you.